# Weird pynotify behaviour in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, pynotify

I wrote a [small app](http://github.com/flavioamieiro/dojotools/) and I am using pynotify to show some messages to the user.

It all works fine here in arch, but when I tested it in Ubuntu, the behaviour was very weird.

Because of the way Ubuntu shows notifications (as what seems to be a rip of of growl), I can't click on them, or interact with them in any way, for that matter.

The biggest problem, however, is that it only shows one notification at a time, and has to wait (a *long* time, by default) untill one of them goes away to show the next one.

Given the nature of the little app I'm writing (a simple monitor that runs a command every time a file is changed), the results must appear to the user in real time.

I have tried to set a small timeout with `message.set_timeout()`, but Ubuntu just seems to ignore it.

--

So, here is my question: Am I the only one to notice that? Am I doing something wrong?

If not, is there any way to change that behaviour in Ubuntu? Any workaround?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu 9.10 replaced upstream's [notification-daemon](http://www.galago-project.org/) with their own [notify-osd](https://launchpad.net/notify-osd), and generally made a mess of things.

You can ensure notification-daemon is installed (via whatever your favorite package manager front-end is) and use it in favor of notify-osd:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled
$ sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.notify-osd /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

Unfortunately this will get overwritten whenever the package is updated... it's already using a dpkg-diversion so it's hard to re-divert it permanently.

Comment: The only problem with this is that when I distribute the app I won't be able to control the environment. Thank you for your answer, though. You pointed in a good direction.

Comment: The solution given actually disables the libnotify notification which is not what i want. Is there any way I can solve that bug?

Comment: @shadyabhi This solution, ideally, replaces Ubuntu's home-developed notifier with the older, upstream notifier, but it's somewhat of a hack.  The best solution I've found: stop using Ubuntu, and switch to a distro that doesn't f*** around patching upstream packages with UI experiments.